# How to connect terrain chunks smoothly?

Tags: unity, procedural-generation, compute-shader

I'm generating a 3D terrain chunk based on Simplex Noise and Marching Cubes algorithm to create mesh.

My chunks have global coordinates (x,y) e.g: (0, 1), (-1, 1)...
Noise is generated using Compute Shader and FastNoiseLite library and calculated like:

```
#pragma kernel GenerateNoise
#include "Includes\FastNoiseLite.compute"

RWStructuredBuffer<float> _Weights;

static const uint numThreads = 8;

int _chunkSize;
int _seed;

float _NoiseScale;
float _Amplitude;
float _Frequency;
int _Octaves;
float _GroundPercent;

float chunkPosX;
float chunkPosY;

int coordToIndex(int x, int y, int z)
{
    return x + _chunkSize * (y + _chunkSize * z);
}

[numthreads(numThreads, numThreads, numThreads)]
void GenerateNoise (uint3 id : SV_DispatchThreadID)
{
    fnl_state noise = fnlCreateState(_seed);
    noise.noise_type = FNL_NOISE_OPENSIMPLEX2;
    noise.fractal_type = FNL_FRACTAL_RIDGED;
    noise.frequency = _Frequency;
    noise.octaves = _Octaves;

    float3 pos = id * _NoiseScale;
    float ground = -pos.y + (_GroundPercent * _chunkSize);
    
    float n = ground + fnlGetNoise3D(noise, id.x * chunkPosX, id.y, id.z * chunkPosY) * _Amplitude;
    _Weights[coordToIndex(id.x, id.y, id.z)] = n;
}
```

My generated chunks look like this:
[image]

My question is: how to connect chunks smoothly?

Comment: Are the chunks supposed to look like that? With a good noise implementation you shouldn't have artifacts like that. And connecting chunks should not be that hard either.

Comment: Thank you for your response. I'm already fixed this problem. The bug was in calculating coordinates of a chunk for noise function. I forgot to multiply chunk coordinate by chunk size.

Comment: So... this question is no longer needed? When you solved your problem on your own, then you should post an own answer. That way others can learn from you and the question no longer appears as unanswered.